# How I get access to my external hard drive?

Tags: permissions, hard-drive, external-hdd

I've changed my hard drive and make the previous one as an external source by USB. Now I want to remove some programs in my external hard drive, but system is not giving me access as he said you don't have permissions to access as you are not the administrator.
Please help I want to free space by uninstalling some programs. Both the hard drives have Linux Ubuntu version 16.04.

Comment: try `gksudo nautilus` to run the file manager as admin

Comment: @ptetteh227 no. You do not run graphical tools with any form of sudo.

Comment: P;ease change the user and group on the external disk to your user and group using your admin account from command line.

Comment: @Rinzwind is there a reason you shouldn't use gksudo for graphical programs?

Comment: Yes. nautilus will change owner and group of the file to "root" where the system expects the owner to be the user. Lots of people got locked out of their desktop when that happens to hidden files inside /home/.  Plus it is VERY VERY VERY easy to make a mistake when being root. 1 small error and you are going to need to reinstall.